# Missing python libraries and include dirs on linux

Tags: python, vim, plugins, development-environment

I want to build YouCompleteMe plugin for vim. Once I run cmake according to the manual, I get errors:

```
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

The problem that I have old Red Had linux and `yum` does give python 2.7. I need to build it from sources. My questions is what exactly should I build for python? What corresponds to python-dev package that is on Ubuntu? What environment paths I should set up and to what values?

How can I figrue out what the path I should setup based on CMake config file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for you to do this is not install python2.7 to your system - but use `pyenv` - https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv to install the specific version of python you need in a local directory (`~/.pyenv./....`)

Now, use `pyenv install -ks 2.7.`0` which will install and compile python 2.7.10 into the ~/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10 directory without touching the rest of your system.

THen in the directory where you try to compile the plugin, do `pyenv local 2.7.10` this will create the file `.python-version` which will control the version that pyenv will use.

The reason to do all this is because if you install the python2.7 into your system, it will mess up other applications whichi may not expect this version.

Also, pyenv will install the `-dev` versions - so, no extra step needed for that